# A way to detect a click anywhere but a specific control?

Tags: elm

In my app the user can click on a div to highlight it.  Is there a way to detect that they've clicked somewhere away from the div?  I'd like to unhighlight selected things when this happens.  I tried adding an onclick to the big div that contains everything else, but that doesn't really work as desired.  IIRC the big div onclick always happens after the contained div onclick, so you can't ever select anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a on "click" event to both the divs and then in the inner div, use `onWithOptions` to stop the propagation of the event. Here's some (untested) code:

```
onClickStop msg =
    onWithOptions "click"
        { stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = False }
        (Json.succeed msg)


view _ =
    div [ onClick Clicked ]
        [ div [ onClickStop NoOp ] []
        ]
```

When the user clicks inside the nested div, the event will be ignored and its propagation to its parent will be cancelled. Only when the user clicks outside the inner div will the `Clicked` message will be sent to `update`.

Comment: Nice!  I was thinking that stopping event propogation was somehow un-elm-ish.  I'll try it!